# Without using a hypervisor, can a process be CPU throttled?

Tags: linux, unix, process

Using `nice` merely gives a "guideline" to the OS, not a hard requirement of priority (ie, if nothing else is begging for attention a nice level of 19 will utilize the full CPU).

Is there a way to absolutely cap a process to, say, no more than 10% of the CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/).

I usually just stick with nice though: if it's running by itself, I don't really care if it's taking up 100%